SwiftUI: unexpected Row height when adding Picker in Form
Recently, When adding a Picker in Form or List in SwiftUI, I got unexpected(bigger) Row height as shown in the first image below and what I expect in the second Image:

What I expect

This is my simple code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedOption: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            Picker("Picker Row", selection: $selectedOption) {
                ForEach(0..<10) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
    
}

What's wrong here? did Apple changed the default row height for picker or am I missing something?

A List applies insets all around each row and also enforces a minimum row height.

Use .listRowInsets on the row (the Picker in this case) to set the vertical insets to 0. If the horizontal insets should remain unchanged then you need to measure the default insets and re-apply them, because I don't think there is a way to set the vertical insets without also setting the horizontal insets.
The minimum row height can be overriden by setting the environment value .defaultMinListRowHeight on the List itself.

List {

    Picker("Picker Row", selection: $selectedOption) {
        // ...
    }
    .border(.blue)
    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
}
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)



That's because you are using Picker inside List, if you want to do so you have to specify the frame. And better wrap text and picker into HStack.
For example add this modifier to List:
.frame(height: 44)

full code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedOption: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Picker Row")
                Spacer()
                Picker("", selection: $selectedOption) {
                    ForEach(0..<10) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 44)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks, I added .frame(height: 0) and I got what!، that's weird! this issue happens in the Form also, I don't remember that you need to set the frame of picker to get the default row height (44).
